# Porting achartengine to Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, achartengine

I'm trying to port [achrtengine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) library to Xamarin.Droid.

What I did is:-

1- Create a new Android Java Bindings Library Project.
2- Add the .jar to Jars folder.
3- set the build action to EmbededJar

but got this error:-

```
'Pan': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

in this line:

```
public event EventHandler Pan {
            add {
                global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.AddEventHandler<global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.IPanListener, global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.IPanListenerImplementor>(
                        ref weak_implementor_AddPanListener,
                        __CreateIPanListenerImplementor,
                        AddPanListener,
                        __h => __h.Handler += value);
            }
            remove {
                global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.RemoveEventHandler<global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.IPanListener, global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.IPanListenerImplementor>(
                        ref weak_implementor_AddPanListener,
                        global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.IPanListenerImplementor.__IsEmpty,
                        RemovePanListener,
                        __h => __h.Handler -= value);
            }
        }
```

I think this is because the class name is Pan too

```
// Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']/class[@name='Pan']"
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("org/achartengine/tools/Pan", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public partial class Pan : global::Org.Achartengine.Tools.AbstractTool {
```

UPDATE:-

I inserted this line to solve this problem

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']/class[@name='Pan']" name="name">PanClass</attr>
```

to change the name of the class.

but got these errors:-

```
Error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AChartEngine.Renderer.XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type' and 'System.Type' (CS0019) (AChartEngineBindings)

Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IntPtr' (CS1503) (AChartEngineBindings)
```

anyone knows how to solve this ?!

Any help is useful.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1935/achartengine-org-jar-binding-error

you should add those to Metadata:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.renderer']/class[@name='XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine']/method[@name='getType' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedName">GetBehaviorType</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.renderer']/class[@name='XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type']" name="managedName">FillOutsideLineBehaviorType</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine']" name="managedName">AChartEngine</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.chart']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Chart</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.model']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Model</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.renderer']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Renderer</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Tools</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.util']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Util</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']/class[@name='Pan']/method[@name='addPanListener']" name="eventName">PanEvent</attr>
```

to rename FillOutsideLine.GetType() and FillOutsideLine.Type to GetBehaviorType() and FillOutsideLineBehaviorType.

and to change the event name too.

I've added the source code to github with example too: https://github.com/mostafa-elabady/Xamarin_achartengine